# Socket.emit() does not send a message in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I have a code that through a connection to a socket, should send to my index another information, also via socket. The problem is that it does not run my sockt.emit after the error event happens.

send.js:

```
var socket = require('../app');
var io = socket.io;
(...)

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('service', function(msg){
    if (msg['action'] == "call"){
      ami.action(
         'Originate',
         {
             Channel: 'SIP/'+msg['orig'],
             Context: 'from-internal',
             Priority: 1,
             Async: 'false',
             Exten: msg['dest']
         },
         function(data){
             if(data.Response == 'Error'){
                 console.log('Originate', data.Message);
                 socket.emit('msg', data.Message);
             }
             else{
               console.log('Originate', data.Message);
             }
         }
      );
    }
  });
});
```

In my index I have only a simple function to handle the return.

index.html:

```
<script>
  var socket = io();
  socket.on('msg', function(msg){
  console.log(msg);
  }); 
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: On the client side, the socket needs to connect to an address

Comment: I already did this but did not solve the problem

Comment: I've also tried with: var socket = io.connect('http:// localhost:7777');